# Fortran MPI problem with copying a communicator

Tags: fortran, mpi, openmpi

I have the following problem with an MPI-Fortran code. The MPI communicator are represented as `INTEGER` in Fortran. But If I consider the following minimal example, I do not get any information from the MPI environment when I am using the copy of the communicator.

```
PROGRAM TEST1
INCLUDE 'mpif.h'
INTEGER :: mpicomm, mpiinfo, mpi_size, mpi_rank, info

CALL MPI_INIT(info)
mpicomm = MPI_COMM_WORLD
WRITE(*,*) "MPI_COMM_WORLD = ", MPI_COMM_WORLD, " mpicomm = ", mpicomm
CALL MPI_COMM_SIZE(mpicomm , mpi_size)
CALL MPI_COMM_RANK(mpicomm , mpi_rank)
WRITE(*,*) mpi_rank, mpi_size

CALL MPI_FINALIZE()
END PROGRAM TEST1
```

I used serveral combinations of OpenMPI 3.0/4.0 and gfortran 7.3/9.1. and in all cases I get:

```
 $ mpirun -np 6 ./a.out 
 MPI_COMM_WORLD =            0  mpicomm =            0
 MPI_COMM_WORLD =            0  mpicomm =            0
 MPI_COMM_WORLD =            0  mpicomm =            0
 MPI_COMM_WORLD =            0  mpicomm =            0
 MPI_COMM_WORLD =            0  mpicomm =            0
 MPI_COMM_WORLD =            0  mpicomm =            0
           0           0
           0           0
           0           0
           0           0
           0           0
           0           0
```

But when I hard-code the `MPI_COMM_WORLD` to the subroutine calls, it works. But looking into `mpif.h` shows that `MPI_COMM_WORLD` is also only a standard Fortran integer.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Replace the line `include 'mpif.h'` with `use mpi`, sort out the linkage issues that (might) arise, and see what error messages pop up.  By using the module rather than including the header file you enable the compiler to check the validity of your calls to subroutines, rather than let them go unchecked, only to cause problems when you run your programs.

Comment: If you simply want to copy or duplicate a communicator I would personally choose the MPI function `MPI_COMM_DUP`. Remember that these communicators declared `integer`  are in fact MPI data types or handles. I would be very careful with just assigning one to another with such data types.

Comment: These are two very different operations, and among other things, one is a collective and the other is local to its given MPI task.